# Setup proxy repos for SBT with Nexus 3

Tags: proxy, sbt, maven-2, ivy, nexus3

I want sbt to use my own nexus server. When i run sbt command in terminal it  downloads plugins and artifacts from central repos.

I found this article that explains how to do that: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

What i've done for now:

1. Installed Nexus 3
2. Created 4 proxy (maven 2) repositories for next repos:

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/

http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/

https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/

These repos are ivy styled (i don't understand exactly what it means), so i hope that it's supported by maven2.

Then i've created group repository (repository/proxy-ivy/) for these 4 repos.

3.
For other artifacts i use already created maven2 repo (repository/maven-public/) that is group for central, snapshots, and hosted repos.

4. I created ~/.sbt/repositories with content:
   [repositories]
   local
   my-maven: http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/
   my-ivy: http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/,[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]

So this is all i have to do to get it to work. No?
I run: sbt -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true

But i see unresolved deps:

> [info] Loading project definition from
>   /home/test/Projects/backend2/project [info] Updating
>   {file:/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/}backend2-build... [info]
>   Resolving io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0 ... [warn]  module not found:
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   /home/test/.ivy2/local/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== my-maven: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.10_0.13/0.8.0/sbt-revolver-0.8.0.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3 ... [warn]
>     module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3 [warn]
>   ==== local: tried [warn]   /home/test/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== my-maven: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.10_0.13/1.0.3/sbt-native-packager-1.0.3.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9 ... [warn]  module not
>   found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   /home/test/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml [warn]
>   ==== my-maven: tried [warn]   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ... [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0: not found [warn]     ::
>   com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3: not found [warn]  ::
>   org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  [warn]   Note:
>   Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these
>   dependencies exist with the requested attributes. [warn]
>         io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.8.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.0.3
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]  [warn]   Note: Unresolved
>   dependencies path: [warn]         io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.8.0
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   (/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2) [warn]          +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]       com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.0.3
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   (/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/plugins.sbt#L2-3) [warn]          +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]       org.scala-sbt:sbt:0.13.9 [warn]           +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0: not found [info] Loading project
>   definition from /home/test/Projects/backend2/project [info] Updating
>   {file:/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/}backend2-build... [info]
>   Resolving io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0 ... [warn]  module not found:
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   /home/test/.ivy2/local/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== my-maven: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.10_0.13/0.8.0/sbt-revolver-0.8.0.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3 ... [warn]
>     module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3 [warn]
>   ==== local: tried [warn]   /home/test/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== my-maven: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.10_0.13/1.0.3/sbt-native-packager-1.0.3.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9 ... [warn]  module not
>   found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   /home/test/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml [warn]
>   ==== my-maven: tried [warn]   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/maven-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom
>   [warn] ==== my-ivy: tried [warn]
>   http://hb.vmc.loc:8081/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ... [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0: not found [warn]     ::
>   com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3: not found [warn]  ::
>   org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  [warn]   Note:
>   Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these
>   dependencies exist with the requested attributes. [warn]
>         io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.8.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.0.3
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]  [warn]   Note: Unresolved
>   dependencies path: [warn]         io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.8.0
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   (/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2) [warn]          +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]       com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.0.3
>   (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   (/home/test/Projects/backend2/project/plugins.sbt#L2-3) [warn]          +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) [warn]       org.scala-sbt:sbt:0.13.9 [warn]           +-
>   default:backend2-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
>   sbtVersion=0.13) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.8.0: not found

Any help is appreciated!